# Is there some way to provide the user a list of existing content in a CPT

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I was looking at the way WordPress uses "Or Link to Existing Content" under the link button in the editor and I am wondering if there is any way I can use that code to allow users to select a page to link to when they create a new custom post.

The context I am talking about is that of slides for a slider linking to content within the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run across this before. What I did was use `get_posts()` to return a list of the pages in the site and making the pages options in a drop down menu in a meta box.

```
// $your_args is an array that you've previously declared to get all the pages.
$pages = get_posts($your_args);

foreach( $pages as $page ) :
?>
<option value="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_name; ?></option>
<?php
endforeach;
```

When you save the post, it will save the page's ID in the custom post's post meta.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this is probably the best available method but I was hoping to get something that handles 1000's of posts; and I'd say it would take a bit of ajax or something to implement that properly, rather than having a huge list. I think I will just let people copy and paste for now.